# Can you say "l’donna" instead of "la donna"?

Tags: grammar, articles

So, I know you can say "l’uomo" and that means the man. Can you say "l’donna" to say the woman instead of "la donna" or is the *l'* in front of uomo exclusively masculine?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a matter of masculine vs feminine. The truncated form *l'* of the definite article can be used only for words starting with vowel. Therefore *l'uomo* is correct but *l'donna* is not.

One point that might be the cause of the confusion is that the sound /w/ (as well as the sound /j/ in words like *ieri*) at the beginning of a word is considered a vowel in Italian, while it is considered a consonant in English, hence in Italian we say *l'uomo* but in English we say *a war* (these sounds are often called semivowels or semiconsonants to emphasize their intermediate state).